# Java Android, How to change images from separate class

Tags: java, android, class, imageview

Please excuse my lack of experience with Java, I have only been working on it for a few weeks so far.
I am trying to create a class which can change images based on ids passed an int[] type.

This is my code:
The main Java file

```
package com.example.imagechangeovertest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        //When image is clicked, trigger StartIt()
        View card_holder = findViewById(R.id.ImageToAlsoChange);
        card_holder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startIt();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start, menu);
        return true;
    }


    //These are the images to change
    public int[] imgIds = {R.id.imageToChange, R.id.ImageToAlsoChange};

    public void startIt(){

        //Set the object up
        ImageReplacer ir = new ImageReplacer();

        //Change the images
        ir.changeImages(imgIds);

    }

}
```

This is the class

```
package com.example.imagechangeovertest;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageReplacer extends StartActivity{

    public ImageReplacer(){

        //TODO - Select random images to replace the images in the layout 

    }

    public void changeImages(int[] image_ids){

        //final <Integer> = new <Integer> changeling;

        for(int i=0; i < 1;i++){//image_ids.length; i++){

            //The image to change
            int changeling = image_ids[i];

            //Find the imageView in the layout - This is where the error occurs NullPointerException
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(changeling);


            //Change the image 
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ti_ti);

        }

    }

}
```

The problem is that if I do this, when I press on the image, I get a NullPointerException and the app closes.
I can make this work if I call this from the same class, just not in this way. I am also not sure if I want to have the class extend the starter activity, but his was the ony way to get it to run.

What have I done wrong? What am I missing?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Where do you want to get the int[] data from? Passing data between activities is done using Intents if that is what you're looking for

Comment: public int[] imgIds = {R.id.imageToChange, R.id.ImageToAlsoChange}; Which may happen 4  or more times in one activity referencing series of different images. The process of doing this, will also create some random data which is used elsewhere.

Comment: Alright. Where are these images? Do you select them from somewhere? Please be specific with the problem. What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I hit return by mistake and edited it. So I have 4 images four times in an activity. They are rhythmic patterns, although this doesn't really matter. I will be generating these rhythm patterns in different activities, which is why I wanted to use an object.

Comment: Ok. But it's still unclear. You have 4 images. You generate them somehow (I'm assuming). Then you want to pass the ids based on some event to another activity?

Comment: I have 4 images presented across the screen which are placeholders. I pass a list of their IDs to the class to tell it which ones I want to change. The class will pick 4 random images which are in the resources already. The image resources get changed to show a 4 beat rhythm pattern. I then do this for the other groups of 4 images. These are questions (spot the rhythm) and the user clicks on the correct rhythm (or not) then their score is updated accordingly. Then a new set of images gets displayed for the next question. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: You then just need to pass the id array via intents to another activity which would show the images. You need to keep calling the same activity I guess. You should read about intents here - http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/241-lesson-28-extras-passing-data-using-intent.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't instantiate Activities like this:

```
    //Set the object up
    ImageReplacer ir = new ImageReplacer();
```

if you want to start a new Activity you should use startActivity(..) method:

```
    startActivity(this, ImageReplacer.class);
```

but in your case looks like it would make more sense to just move that method for the image replacing to the main activity. Or is there anything that prevents you from doing this?

Or set the ImageReplacer Activity as the Main Activity (the one that gets launched first) then you will have the method available in your activity and don't need to launch another activity just for this.

**Update:**
If you want different activities that have your image handling method you could adjust your code like this:

Make ImageReplacer extend Activity:

```
 public class ImageReplacer extends Activity {
 // your image-handling code here
```

this will be your Base-Class for Image related Activities!

Then your StartActivity should extend ImageReplacer:

```
 public class StartActivity extends ImageReplacer {
 // your StartActivity will have image handling code inherited from ImageReplacer now
 // no need to instantiate or start another Activity for that
```

in fact I recommend to rename your class to ImageReplacerActivity. That way it is more clear that it is an activity.

Comment: Oh, what is the difference? I wanted to put it in a separate class so that I could use it in different activities (although using extends I suppose makes that impossible).

Comment: yes you can use extends but I would make it a bit different, let me update answer..